# NTLM authentication to AD FS for non-IE browser without 'Extended Protection' switched off?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ntlm, adfs2.0, adfs

When using NTLM authentication to AD FS 2.0, from Google Chrome or Firefox 3.5+ running on Windows, then this results in a repeated sign-in dialog and finally sign-in failure, with 'Audit Failure' events with "Status: 0xc000035b".

This can be 'solved' by switching off 'Extended Protection' for the "/adfs/ls" web application in IIS.  This is documented in several places; see [my answer to another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436441/adfs-authentication-ie8-works-chrome-fails/5437077#5437077) for details.

My question is: How can one make NTLM authentication to AD FS work for these browsers *without* switching off 'Extended Protection'?  I mean, in Internet Explorer this works fine with 'Extended Protection' on, why don't Chrome or Firefox?  Or is this a Chrome/Firefox implementation bug/restriction, e.g., in their use of the Windows NTLM library?

*Update:* I should have mentioned that I'd like to do this without forcing people to make changes in their browser settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237448(v=ws.10).aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2461628/en-us

this is a Chrome / Firefox / Safari implementation restriction if

- the client is running Windows 7 *and* the server has `ExtendedProtectionTokenCheck` set to
  `Require` or `Allow`
- the client is running Windows XP or Vista - without appropriate updates(!) *and* the server has `ExtendedProtectionTokenCheck` set to
  `Require`

Maybe you can suppress Extended Protection on your clients with this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976918/en-us

> [...]
>   To control the extended protection behavior, create the following
>   registry subkey:
>   **Key Name:** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA
>   **Value Name:** SuppressExtendedProtection
>   **Type:** DWORD
>
> For Windows clients that support channel binding that are failing to
>   be authenticated by non-Windows Kerberos servers that do not handle
>   the CBT correctly:
>   **1.** Set the registry entry value to “**0x01**.”
> This will
>   configure Kerberos not to emit CBT tokens for unpatched applications.
>   **2.** If that does not resolve the problem, then set the registry entry
>   value to “**0x03**.”
> This will configure Kerberos never to emit CBT
>   tokens.
>
> [...]

Comment: And the bounty is coming your way.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Marnix Cool, thx :) - Did the registry hack work for you then?

Comment: Haven't been able to check the registry hack yet, but I was looking for a server-side setting, and that's what the linked docs provide.  This way we can tell our customers: "Sorry, non-IE doesn't work without this server side setting, see here for MSFT's information."  But when I try the registry hack, I'll comment on that here.

Comment: @Marnix: The registry hack worked for me with Chrome.  Immediately after creating the SuppressExtendedProtection=0x1 value, I was able to sign in to office365.com after just one password dialog, whereas before it would repeatedly ask for credentials until failing.

Answer (score 0):

Extended Protection was designed to prevent kerberos ticket replay attacks.

As I understand it, it works in IE because the default for ADFS is Windows Integrated Authentication which IE handles "under the hood".

When I investigated this a while back, if I remember correctly, there is a workaround for Firefox.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, I think, which is more about _why_ IWA (Integrated Windows Authentication) behaves differently between IE and Firefox/Chrome.  But I would be interested to know what one would need to change on the client side to make Firefox work.